# Issue with ng-bind-html

Tags: html, angularjs, ngsanitize

I'm trying to create a website using angular-js .I'm using rest api calls for getting data. I'm using ngSanitize as the data from rest call includes html character. Even if i use ng-bind-html in my view the html tags are not removed .What is the mistake in my code.Can anyone help me

```js
var app = angular.module('app',['ngSanitize','ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller("ctrl",['$scope','$http','$location','$uibModal',function($scope,$http,$location,$uibModal,){
  //here im making my rest api call and saving the data in to $scope.items;
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="hov" ng-repeat ="item in items">
  <br/>
  <div>
    <hr class="divider" style="overflow:auto;">
      <ul>
        <li style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:900px;">
          <h3>Name<span style="color:#0899CC;" ng-model="id2" ng-bind-html="item.name"></span></h3>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h4>Description: <span ng-bind-html="item.description"></span></h4>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please provide more code like what is "item.description" from were you get it and show the object "items"

Comment: dude im making a ajax call . and the data are confidentials

Comment: there is nothing to do with my rest api calls or my data for answering this question

Comment: what the data that you give to the dom! if you want help just provided it

Comment: &lt;p&gt;testing only for checking ui&lt;/p&gt; this is my sample response

Comment: i want this  to be printed  just as - testing only for checking ui

Answer (score 0):

So you want to allow HTML tags or deny them ?

If you want the html to be escaped in the data coming from your server, just use `ng-bind`. It will replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;` thus showing the HTML tags instead of computing them.

#### If you want to completely remove any HTML tags

Try this filter

```
filter('htmlToPlaintext', function() {
    return function(text) {
      return  text ? String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';
    };
  }
);
```

then in your HTML :

```
<h3>Name<span style="color:#0899CC;" ng-model="id2" ng-bind-html="item.name | htmlToPlaintext"></span></h3>
```

#### If you trust the source and want to compute the HTML it send you

You can use this filter

```
app.filter('trusted', function($sce){
        return function(html){
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(html)
        }
     });
```

then in your HTML :

```
<h3>Name<span style="color:#0899CC;" ng-model="id2" ng-bind-html="item.name | trusted"></span></h3>
```

And

```
<h4>Description: <span ng-bind-html="item.description | trusted"></span></h4>
```

Comment: bro in my view im getting <p> <span> and all. i tried ng-bind-html its not working.

Comment: and i tried with the filter directive but didnt helped me

Comment: So instead of getting <p><span>... in your view what do you want exactly ? Do you want the HTML tags to be computed by the browser (ie : get paragraphs and spans) or do you want to remove all the tags ? I've edited my answer for the case you want to remove all tags

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem before some time , then i created a filter for this problem, You can use this filter to do sanitize your html code:

```
app.filter("sanitize", ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(htmlCode) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
    }
}]);
```

in html you can use like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="businesses.oldTimings | sanitize"></div>
```

businesses.oldTimings  is $scope variable having description of strings or having strings with html tags , $scope.businesses.oldTimings  is the part of particular controller that you are using for that html.

see in the snapshot:

[image]

**you can use limitHtml filter to do the same:**

```
app.filter('limitHtml', function() {
    return function(text, limit) {
        var changedString = String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '  ');
        var length = changedString.length;
        return changedString.length > limit ? changedString.substr(0, limit - 1) : changedString;
    }
});
```

**Then you can add bothe filter in your html like that:**

```
<p class="first-free-para" ng-bind-html="special.description| limitHtml : special.description.length | sanitize">
```

**Hope it will work for you.**

Comment: bro can you also provide me the cdn src you have used

Comment: brother, if you are using angular then dont need to do so.Just go to your file where you have created angular.module('app',....
and add this filter to your app.like this:


var app = angular.module('app',['ngSanitize','ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller("ctrl",['$scope','$http','$location','$uibModal',function($scope,$http,$location,$uibModal,){
  //here im making my rest api call and saving the data in to $scope.items;
  }]);

app.filter("sanitize", ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(htmlCode) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
    }
}]);

And use in html .

Comment: after creating this filter, go in your html where you are doing this : ng-bind-html="item.name"    but in place of this you need to write ng-bind-html="item.name | sanitize".   Hopefully it will work

Comment: i doubt that ngSantize version is the issue

Comment: <p> ,<br> tags are getting displayed

Comment: try after removing ngSanitize from your app.js

Comment: Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.

Comment: this thing was working fine when i was using ng-route. Now i changed it into multiple pages .my requirement is now multi page app